# Accordion scroll down when we navigate through the accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an accordion which will have 3 - 4 elements and contents of each accordion will show at the accordion  of accordion  when clicked any of the accordion

let us say i have accordion ..

```
ONE
TWO
THREE
```

by default accordion should show collapsed contents at the after the last accordion element

like

```
ONE (This is active on page load)
TWO
THREE
accordion  contents should show up here & for other shoul also show up here when a user
```

click on any of the accordion (ONE, TWO. THREE)

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gmcLnowa/9/

```
<div class="header"> this is a header</div>
<div class="contents"> <p>Page text will be here </p>
<p>Page text will be here </p>
<p>Page text will be here </p>
<p>Page text will be here </p>
<p>Page text will be here </p></div>
<div id="accordion">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#one">Example one</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#two">Example two</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#three">Example three</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="one" class="accordion">ONE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium.</div>
    <div id="two" class="accordion">TWO Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium.</div>
    <div id="three" class="accordion">THREE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium.</div>
</div>
```

By default it will scroll up as click event is fired for showing the contents of the first accordion. How to stop scrolling when navigating between accordions.

Comment: -1 your question makes no sense, title is littered with spelling errors.

Comment: Where are you using `accordion` apart from class name? __Not related to jQuery UI accordion__

Comment: Just want to give you some solution but your question is weird and collapsed and even couldn't able to understand.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/gmcLnowa/11/

Comment: @wiesion, I didn't get your point. example you have show scroll down the page header is not visible. Please scroll up and then click on any accordion  you will notice page scrolls down to active accordion contents

Comment: @RobSchmuecker, Thanks for at least pointing why you have down-voted. other people sometimes down-vote & dont give any reason.. I have updated my question hope that may explain what i am trying to say.

Comment: with your updated question i think now what you want to achieve, but since you're using :target you are very limited in terms of event handling. for a workaround have a look at http://csscience.com/css3-tabs/

Comment: @wiesion, i think this can help, let me try to modify it to make it work like i want..

Comment: I thought your usage of a js-less accordion with #target and :target is a feature, if you go now for JS why not do so from the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really very misleading as this is then not an `accordion`.

However to remedy your scrolling issue, this is because your are using destination anchors (http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/struct/links.html) as your links and the default behaviour is to jump to the position referenced.

What you need to do is to change the `href` to some other attribute such as the `data` attribute and then react accordingly.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gmcLnowa/12/

CSS changed to:

```
a[data-mytarget="#one"].active{
    background:blue !important;
}
a[data-mytarget="#two"].active{
    background:red !important;
}
a[data-mytarget="#three"].active{
    background:yellow !important;
}
```

JS changed to:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    var mytarget = $(this).data('mytarget');
    $('.accordion').hide();
    $(mytarget).show();
    $(this).addClass("active");
})
$("a:first")[0].click()
```

and HTML changed to :

```
<ul>
    <li> <a data-mytarget="#one">Example one</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a data-mytarget="#two">Example two</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a data-mytarget="#three">Example three</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code for a basic simple accordion using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.item').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).next('.item-data').css('display') != 'block') {
            $('.active').slideUp('fast').removeClass('active');
            $(this).next('.item-data').addClass('active').slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            $('.active').slideUp('fast').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

**MARKUP**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='item'>Item 1</div>
    <div class='item-data'>
        <div>This is the content for Accordion 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>Item 2</div>
    <div class='item-data'>
        <div>This is the content for Accordion 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>Item 3</div>
    <div class='item-data'>
        <div>This is the content for Accordion 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>Item 4</div>
    <div class='item-data'>
        <div>This is the content for Accordion 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/avhytfef/)**

Comment: Thank you, but my accordion works in a different way rather than showing contents of that accordion  under each element i need to show them after all the accordions tabs

Comment: Do you need accordion or tabbed content